# ToolbarSearch not being customized in the UI

Tags: css, codenameone

According to [this blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/toolbar-search-mode.html), it should be possible to style the ToolbarSearch by customizing the UIIDs `ToolbarSearch`,`TextFieldSearch` and `TextHintSearch.

In my CSS File it looks like this:

```
ToolbarSearch {
    color: white;
    height:30mm;
    width:30mm;
}

TextHintSearch {
    color: white;
    height:30mm;
    width:30mm;
}

TextFieldSearch {
    color: white;
    height:30mm;
    width:30mm;
}
```

The main thing I want to achieve is a **white** Search Button, Text, `X`-Button and Hint.

In the blog post above, it looks right, except the textfieldsearch and -hint:

[image]

But in my application it looks like this:

[image]
[image]

The buttons are in the wrong color. What am I doing wrong?

Notice:

This is how I add it

```
this.getToolbar().addSearchCommand(e -> {
    //TODO search
});
```

(The algorythm is not implemented yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the CSS plugin so I'm not really sure how this maps there but you need to override the selected/pressed & unselected styles.

Comment: neither editing in css, nor editing in designer works